# Picture in a value = (HTML)

Tags: html, css, image, button, src

How could I put an image inside my HTMl part of the code

`<input id="sendButton" type="button" value=<img src="sendbutton.jpg"> />`

I thought this would work but when I run the website it just shows as text "img src />"

Is there any way I could do this?

What this is about is a send button for a chat application, initially I had
`<input id="sendButton" type="button" value="Send" />`
Which worked perfectly and showed the button as "Send", but I would love to use an image in there like twitter, instagram etc... does.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is simplly broken/invalid HTML.  If you want a button which contains an image, but the image inside of a button:

```
<button id="sendButton">
  <img src="sendbutton.jpg">
</button>
```

If (less likely, but anything is possible) you want the *value* of an *input* to be an HTML string, it needs to be HTML-encoded:

```
<input id="sendButton" type="button" value="&lt;img src=&quot;sendbutton.jpg&quot;&gt;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this basic syntax and then customize it

```
 <button type="submit" id="sendButton"><img src="sendbutton.jpg"></button>
```